# XSS and PHP Attacks

Tags: php, javascript, xss, code-injection

I have been assigned to test a website that another group has just created. I have discovered

that it is prone to XSS attacks. However, it does not really throw

up an error or any valid information when I use JS with PHP:

```
i.e. var someVar = <?php echo 'a'; ?>

     alert(someVar);
```

This led to my assuming that a site prone to XSS attacks may not necessarily allow php code

to be injected. Am I correct? If not, is there anything with the segment that I posted above?

And, the reason I haven't tried php injection via the GET variables is that I do

not use anything of the form **page.php?id=''**, that queries the database, as of now, except for

the registration and login part, which is via POST.

Comment: Careful, POST is as sensitive as GET, Sir... For the rest of the question, I don't understand what you're trying to explain, sorry abt that.

Comment: XSS (cross-site scripting) is all about injecting `<script>`s and altering existing ones' functionality. Read a bit more on the topic: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Output is not something you generally need to worry about. It's how you handle submitted data that is the weak link. If a user may post JS that will be executed, make sure the output is only accessible by that user. Never ever let users post server-executed code.

Comment: How do I check for PHP injection, if any, using the above technique, if possible?

Comment: You don't, you never trust user submitted code by never executing it.

Answer (score 2):

> This led to my assuming that a site prone to XSS attacks may not necessarily allow php code to be injected. Am I correct?

Yes, of course.
XSS attacks has nothing to do with PHP code injections. It's all about JS code injection

Comment: I +1 your answer because you resemble your handle.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs on a client side, Php runs on a server side. There's no way you can execute php on a client side using JavaScript. Check more at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

What you can try to do is posting some js code wrapped in  tag from any website input field, if it's value isn't validating on a server side and goes directly to db and displaying somewhere on site pages after you'l see js code executing, as other clients will do, so js code may do some funny stuff on client computers